# During importing from Eclipse to Android Studio, what does "Obsolete dependency configuration found: compile View usage" mean?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

Importing to `Android Studio 4.0.1` my seven-year old brief Android app code, which I wrote on KitKat and  `Eclipse`, works fine.

This is a very small app that serves as an experimental ground for my actual app.

I am getting the two issues:

- "*compile/libs/android-support-v4.jar*" "*Obsolete dependency configuration found: compile View usage*".
- "*compile/libs/libspen23.jar*" "*Obsolete dependency configuration found: compile View usage*".

Clicking on the offered "*Update compile to implementation*" twice works nicely (good job, Android Studio team!).

I'd now like to have a bit more understanding about this last issue. What does "*Obsolete dependency configuration found: compile View usage*" mean? (I definitely need `libspen23.jar`, but I'm not sure whether `android-support-v4.jar` will be needed or, indeed, why I needed it in the first place.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message means that you must make changes on your `build.Gradle (module: app)` file, because `compile` is deprecated. So replace `compile` with `implementation` and use the adequate library version. Hope that will help you.[image]